# Android TextView use with multiple fonts (languages)

Tags: android, internationalization, textview

I have a textview which is preloaded with some content. what i want is to display certain part of the content in english n some in chinese. Say for example i have three paragraphs in english then each such paragraph is to be followed with chinese para. I can't use spanning of the content since the length varies. Please provide me with the solution for this or a better alternative.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can format it in the `HTML` way like this:

**`MyTypeFace.class`**

```
package my.app;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.text.style.TypefaceSpan;

public class MyTypeFace extends TypefaceSpan {
private final Typeface newType;
public MyTypeFace(String family, Typeface type) {
    super(family);
    newType = type;
}
@Override
public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
    applyCustomTypeFace(ds, newType);
}
@Override
public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint paint) {
    applyCustomTypeFace(paint, newType);
}
private static void applyCustomTypeFace(Paint paint, Typeface tf) {
    int oldStyle;
    Typeface old = paint.getTypeface();
    if (old == null) {
        oldStyle = 0;
    } else {
        oldStyle = old.getStyle();
    }
    int fake = oldStyle & ~tf.getStyle();
    if ((fake & Typeface.BOLD) != 0) {
        paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
    }
    if ((fake & Typeface.ITALIC) != 0) {
        paint.setTextSkewX(-0.25f);
    }
    paint.setTypeface(tf);
}
}
```

Now,Just go on to fetch the stories from the `String.xml`, apply the typeface on them,and Display them.

```
String text1=findViewById(R.string.text1);  
String text2=findViewById(R.string.text2);  

TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_fonts);  
txt.setTextSize(30);
Typeface font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "english.ttf");
Typeface font2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "chinese.ttf");   
text1.setSpan (new MyTypeFace("", font1), 0, 4,Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
text2.setSpan (new MyTypeFace("", font2), 4, 11,Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
String totalText=text1+"<br>"+text2;  
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(totalText));
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but i think this will not solve my problem...i had mentioned that each english para has to be followed by a para in chinese... if i use two String variables they'll contain the enitre data n formatting would not be easy... It's like how we do translation of content from one language to the other and so i want the solution regarding that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but even this will not work exactly...let me give u some example that might help u out..Say i have a story in english n i would like it to be translated to chinese..now using the string.xml in resource I set the content of the textview..say i have the story in 5 paragraphs...so i display the first para in englisg followed by its chinese para..so i need to have 2 typeface fonts,one for english n one for chinese...secondly i may have 100 of such stories whose number of para may vary from 1 to any given integer so i can't intialize i=10 or any other number.

Comment: can we set different fonty type i mean diff font faces on a single piece of text in textview without spaning the test?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to figured it out from this sample:

```
TextView text = new TextView(context);
text.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + "some text" + "</b>" +  "<br />" + 
            "<small>" + "some text" + "</small>" + "<br />" + 
            "<small>" + "some text" + "</small>"));
```